# WordPress: Display caption or description for non image media like PDF

Tags: wordpress, hook, wysiwyg

I'm using the Add Media button above the WYSIWYG editor to display links to uploaded PDF files, and I want to show the uploaded file's caption or description field, but WordPress only shows this meta data for image files.

Is there a hook that I can use to expose the caption or description fields for PDF files too?

Answer (score 0):

```
function dispSelectedPdf() {
  sProdPdfTable = ""; sProd_pdf_ids = new Array(); sProd_pdf_urls = new Array();
    tx_selected_pdf.forEach(function(row, index, array) {
        if(row[0] != null && row[0] > 0) {
        sProd_pdf_ids.push(row[0]); sProd_pdf_urls.push(row[1]);
        var str = row[1];
        var slash = str.lastIndexOf('/');
        var file_name_downloadable = str.substring(slash + 1);
sProdPdfTable += '<div class="prod_sel_content"><a href="'+row[1]+'" target="_blank" class="btn btn-lincoln prod_sel_img"><button type="button" class="for_pdf_button equal" style="cursor:pointer;"><span class="dashicons dashicons-portfolio"></span><hr>'+file_name_downloadable+'</button></a></div>';
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is this? When do I call this method?

Comment: this function should be called inside your upload fuction at the end.tx_selected pdf is the array which you use inside your upload function replace that with your's and then use a foreach to retrieve the data from the array